# Under what circumstances, if any, can ReadFile hang after WSAEventSelect said it was ready?

Tags: sockets, winapi, tcp, readfile

This is rather ugly. We're getting weird hangups caused (read: triggered) by some security scanning software. I suspect it has a nonstandard TCP/IP stack, and the customer is asking why hangups.

Static analysis suggests only two possible locations for the hangup. The hangup either has to be in `ReadFile()` or `WriteFile()` on a socket; and `WriteFile()` cannot hang here unless the scanner is designed to make `WriteFile()` hang by setting the window size to zero. If `WriteFile()` were to return at all even if it didn't make progress I'd be able to knock the thing out of its wedged state. I also don't think the log state is consistent with `WriteFile()` returning.

So onto `ReadFile()`: this is the calling sequence:

```c
    SOCKET conn;
    HANDLE unwedgeEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    HANDLE listenEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (listenEvent == NULL) return;
    //...
    conn = accept(lstn);
    for (;;) {
        HANDLE wakeup[2];
        wakeup[0] = unwedgeEvent;
        wakeup[1] = listenEvent;
        if (WSAEventSelect(conn, socket, FD_READ | FD_CLOSE) == 0) {
            // Log error 
            break;
        }
        which = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, wakeup, FALSE, INFINITE);
        if (which < 0) {
           // Log error
           break;
        }
        if (which == 1) {
            DWORD read;
            r = ReadFile(conn, chunk, 4096, &read, NULL);
            if (r == 0) {
                // Handle error -- not stuck here
            } else {
                // Handle data -- not stuck here either
            }
        }
        if (which == 0) break;
    }
```

Where signalling `unwedgeEvent` doesn't manage to accomplish anything and the thread remains stuck forever.

So the real question is have I gone nuts or is this really a thing that can happen?

So this has gone somewhat off the deep end; I don't need non-blocking sockets at all. I need a `select()` that takes handle arguments to things that are sockets and things that are not sockets.

The following API sequences do not hang in ReadFile:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
Sender                                 B Receiver
                                         WSAEventSelect
                                       * WaitForMultipeObjects
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
                                         WSAEventSelect
                                       * WaitForMultipeObjects
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
................................................................
                                         WSAEventSelect
                                       * WaitForMultipeObjects
send(buffer size = 2)
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
                                         WaitForMultipeObjects
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
................................................................
                                         WSAEventSelect
                                       * WaitForMultipeObjects
send(buffer size = 1)
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
                                         WaitForMultipeObjects
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
................................................................
                                         WSAEventSelect
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         WaitForMultipeObjects
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
                                         WaitForMultipeObjects
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
................................................................
                                         WSAEventSelect
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         WaitForMultipeObjects
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         ReadFile(size = 2)
                                       * WaitForMultipeObjects
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
................................................................
                                         WSAEventSelect
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         WaitForMultipeObjects
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
send(buffer size = 1)
                                         WaitForMultipeObjects
                                         ReadFile(size = 1)
```

Comment: Where are `conn`, `socket`, and `unwedgeEvent` being assigned? Also, you are not checking the return values of `WSAEventSelect()` or `WaitForMultipleObjects()` for failures (and you should be using `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` instead of `WaitForMultipleObjects()` anyway). Also, you are not calling `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` at all to determine if `FD_READ` was the actual type of event triggered **and to clear the socket's event state and reset events**. Also, why are you using `ReadFile()` instead of `recv()` or `WSARecv()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `conn` is assigned from `accept()` which wasn't where the hangup was. (Which I can tell because the `listen` buffer was full.) I double-checked; the omitted error handling was for brevity in asking the question, which in hindsight was a mistake.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I don't suppose you can get an answer together for `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()`; I'm trying to gather enough information to test the hypothesis, which is really annoying because I don't know how to reproduce the hangup in dev yet.

Comment: If you don't want to block in `ReadFile` / `recv` / `recvfrom`, mark the socket as non-blocking.  Checking for events is a performance optimization, while the non-blocking mode is what affects correctness.

Comment: @BenVoigt "*mark the socket as non-blocking*" - `WSAEventSelect()` handles that for you, per its documentation: "*The WSAEventSelect function automatically sets socket s to nonblocking mode, regardless of the value of lNetworkEvents.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: After some hours debugging; I figured out why it's using ReadFile and WriteFile. If the socket is originally created as blocking, ReadFile and WriteFile don't care that WSAEventSelect changed it to non-blocking (and the code depends on WriteFile blocking even though ReadFile should never block).

Comment: @Joshua: As far as I'm aware, all sockets are always created as blocking.  With `WSASocket` you can use `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` but that is not the same as `FIONBIO`

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's what I thought too; but then I took a socket handle created by .NET Runtime and passed it to ReadFile and it said incorrect parameter; I then swapped for a socket created by WSASocket and it worked.

Comment: @BenVoigt `socket()` does create a blocking socket, but one with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` enabled by default.

Comment: @Joshua .NET Socket objects and Winsock socket handles are not the same thing,

Comment: @Joshua "*I need a `select()` that takes handle arguments to things that are sockets and things that are not sockets*"` - `select()` supports only socket handles. `WaitFor(Single|Multiple)Object(s)/Ex()` and `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` support socket events (not socket handles!) and non-socket handles.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I feel like you're not quite seeing the thing here. The normal pattern is you call `select()` on the socket list, and you then operate on the normal blocking sockets because you know which calls will not hang forever (you can and do get some blocking as whenever you write, you block). Now try to implement it with an event that breaks the loop. I used to use a socket for this and people would question this bizarre self-connected socket that would show up in netstat.

Comment: @Joshua "*The normal pattern is*" - I've been programing with sockets for over 20 years, I know the patterns. "*Now try to implement it with an event that breaks the loop*" - on Windows, you need to use non-blocking/overlapped IO on the socket so you can handle the break event. On *nix systems instead, for instance, `select()` supports file descriptors, such as from `pipe()`, which you can use to break a blocking `select()`/`(e)poll()` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of issues with your code:

- You should use `WSACreateEvent()` and `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` instead of `CreateEvent()` and `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. Although the *current* implementation is that the former APIs simply map to the latter APIs, Microsoft is free to change that implementation at any time without breaking code that uses the former APIs properly.
- In your call to `WSAEventSelect()`, `socket` should be `listenEvent` instead.
- `WSAEventSelect()` returns `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1) on failure, not 0 like you have coded.
- You are not calling `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` at all, which you need to do in order to determine if `FD_READ` was the actual type of event triggered, and to **clear the socket's event state and reset the event object**.  So, you may be acting on a stale read state, which could explain why you end up calling `ReadFile()` when there is actually nothing available to read.
- `WSAEventSelect()` puts the socket into non-blocking mode (per its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaeventselect)), so it is actually not possible for `ReadFile()` (or any other reading function) to block on the socket. However, it could fail immediately with a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error, so make sure you are not treating that condition as a fatal error.
- The `WSAEventSelect()` documentation does not list `ReadFile()` as a supported function for re-enabling events when calling `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()`. Although the [Socket Handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/socket-handles-2) documentation does say that a Winsock `SOCKET` *can* be used with non-Winsock I/O functions like `ReadFile()`, it *recommends* that a `SOCKET` should only be used with Winsock functions.  So, you *should* use `send()`/`recv()` or `WSASend()`/`WSARecv()` instead of `WriteFile()`/`ReadFile()`.

With that said, try something more like the following:

```
HANDLE unwedgeEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
if (unwedgeEvent == NULL) {
    // Log error 
    return;
}

...

SOCKET conn = accept(lstn, NULL, NULL);
if (conn == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    // Log error 
    return;
}

...

WSAEVENT listenEvent = WSACreateEvent();
if (listenEvent == NULL) {
    // Log error 
}
else if (WSAEventSelect(conn, listenEvent, FD_READ | FD_CLOSE) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    // Log error 
}
else {
    WSAEVENT wakeup[2];
    wakeup[0] = (WSAEVENT) unwedgeEvent;
    wakeup[1] = listenEvent;

    char chunk[4096];               
    int read;

    do {
        DWORD which = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, wakeup, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
        if (which == WSA_WAIT_FAILED) {
            // Log error
            break;
        }

        if (which == WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0) {
            break;
        }

        if (which == (WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0+1)) {
            WSANETWORKEVENTS events = {};
            if (WSAEnumNetworkEvents(conn, listenEvent, &events) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                // Log error
                break;
            }

            if (events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ) {
                read = recv(conn, chunk, sizeof(chunk), 0);
                if (read == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
                        // Log error
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (read == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    // Handle chunk up to read number of bytes
                }
            }

            if (events.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (true);

    WSACloseEvent(listenEvent);
}

closesocket(conn);
```

Comment: In addition to all that, it would be best to place the socket into non-blocking mode.  `WSAEventSelect` is a good way to run non-blocking sockets more efficiently; it is not a way to avoid blocking on a blocking socket.

Comment: @BenVoigt "*place the socket into non-blocking mode*" - `WSAEventSelect()` handles that for you, per its documentation: "*The WSAEventSelect function automatically sets socket s to nonblocking mode, regardless of the value of lNetworkEvents.*"

Comment: Well that makes OP's believed symptoms entirely impossible, not-withstanding the failure to call `WSAEnumNetworkEvents`, because even if there is no read event pending then `recv` should not block it should set last-error to `EWOULDBLOCK`.  Thus failure to enumerate pending events is only a missed optimization.  Perhaps the entire problem is from calling `ReadFile` when `recv` should have been used.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It took me two and a half hours of debugging to get an explanation for that one. `WSAEventSelect()` sets the socket to non-blocking but ReadFile does not care, and neither does WriteFile. I can change ReadFile to a non-blocking call but I need WriteFile to block under normal operation.

Comment: @Joshua: Yeah, `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` normally have blocking or non-blocking behavior controlled by OVERLAPPED, not FIONBIO

Comment: @Joshua If the socket is set to non-blocking, you can't perform blocking operations on it. Since you are performing non-blocking reads, you will have to perform non-blocking writes as well. If you need the writer to block, then simply wait for a non-blocking write operation to complete, such as by calling `send()` in a loop (with `select()` or `WSAEventSelect()` to know when it is safe to write) until `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` is no longer reported, or use Overlapped I/O with `WSASend()` and `WSAGetOverlappedResult()` set to `fWait=TRUE`.

Comment: "So, you may be acting on a stale read state" I'm trying to work this angle. Despite all of the other stuff that doesn't explain the failure mode, this would explain it if I can find a way to make the state of the socket not agree with the state of the event handle. This isn't easy because it's an auto reset event.

Comment: @Joshua "*This isn't easy because it's an **auto reset** event*" - maybe that is the crux of the problem? Why are you using auto-reset instead of manual-reset? `WSACreateEvent()` creates a manual-reset event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Hmmm. If I switch it to a manual reset event I get the hangup every time. But an auto reset event is used to reset the event immediately on WaitForMultipleObjects(). Is that why you couldn't find what was resetting the event?